# Creating a service for snmpd.exe on windows server + Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, snmp

I need to create a service for the snmp daemon snmpd.exe which is installed on my windows server 2016.
I use `sc create snmpd binPath= "C:/path/to/snmpd.exe"` and then I try to start it with `sc start snmpd` but I get the following error:

*The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.*

How can I create a working service for this binary please ?
I'm using cygwin with my windows server if it helps.

I do not need to make it work in that exact way, any other solutions are welcome, I just need a working service with this binary.

PS: I only have an ssh access to the server

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest download the Windows 2003 resource kit - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657 - to get the tools: Instsrv.exe and Srvany.exe.  You can use these to create a service out of what I assume isn't a service.  See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to install a Cygwin program as service is to use the `cygserver` 
utility.

```
$ cygrunsrv --help
Usage: cygrunsrv [OPTION]...

Main options: Exactly one is required.

  -I, --install <svc_name>  Installes a new service named <svc_name>.
  -R, --remove <svc_name>   Removes a service named <svc_name>.
  -S, --start <svc_name>    Starts a service named <svc_name>.
  -E, --stop <svc_name>     Stops a service named <svc_name>.
  -Q, --query <svc_name>    Queries a service named <svc_name>.
  -L, --list [server]       Lists services that have been installed
                            with cygrunsrv.
  <svc_name> can be a local service or "server/svc_name" or "server\svc_name".
  ....
```

Any other way will fail to proper execute the program.
See for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704903/running-cygwin-application-as-a-windows-service?rq=1